# Is there a way to loop through a dataframe and assign a value in a new column based on a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have one dataframe with 2 columns and I want to add a new column;

This new column should be updated based on a list that I have:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,6,7,9,10]
```

The new column is only updated with the list value if the flag (in col2) is 1.
If flag is 0, do not populate row in new column.

Current DF

```
+-------------+---------+
| context     | flag    |
+-------------+---------+
| 0           |       1 |
| 0           |       1 |
| 0           |       0 |
| 2           |       1 |
| 2           |       1 |
| 2           |       1 |
| 2           |       1 |
| 2           |       0 |
| 4           |       1 |
| 4           |       1 |
| 4           |       0 |
+-------------+---------+
```

Desired DF

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| context     | flag    | new_context |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 0           |       1 |           0 |
| 0           |       1 |           1 |
| 0           |       0 |             |
| 2           |       1 |           2 |
| 2           |       1 |           3 |
| 2           |       1 |           6 |
| 2           |       1 |           7 |
| 2           |       0 |             |
| 4           |       1 |           9 |
| 4           |       1 |          10 |
| 4           |       0 |             |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

Right now, I loop through the indices of the list and assign the list value to the new_context column. Then I increment to go through the list.
The values are populated in the correct spots but they all say 0. I don't believe it's iterating through the list properly.

```
list_length = len(list)
i=0
for i in range(list_length])):  
    df["new_context"] = [list[i] if ele == 0 else "" for ele in df["flag"]]
    if df["flag"] == 0: i+=1
```

I have also tried to iterate through the entire dataframe, however I think it's just applying the same list value (first list value of 0)

```
i=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df["new_context"] = [list[i] if ele == 0 else "" for ele in df["flag"]]
    if row['flag'] == 0: i+=1
```

How can I use the next list value to populate the new column where the flag=1?
It seems i+=1 is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
l = [0,1,2,3,6,7,9,10]
df['New']=''
df.loc[df.flag==1,'New']=l
df
Out[80]: 
    context  flag New
0         0     1   0
1         0     1   1
2         0     0    
3         2     1   2
4         2     1   3
5         2     1   6
6         2     1   7
7         2     0    
8         4     1   9
9         4     1  10
10        4     0
```

Comment: thank you! worked like a charm. Didnt know how to use the df.loc in pandas.